# Convert unique string ids to unique integer ids in python

Tags: python

I have a list of unique string ids taken from a data set, however I can't feed them into the machine learning model I wish to use; for this they must be converted to a float/integer. What is the best way to do this in Python?

If I have a list like:

```
user_ids = ['8842281e1d1347389f2ab93d60773d4d', 
'8842281e1d1347389f2ab93d60773d4d']
```

How can I convert it to:

```
user_ids = [12126519648818767841447120547826, 
95586587481861384824287499822085]
```

The string ids can be repeated in the list so it would be ideal for the float/integer version to map to a string id.

Comment: What's the conversion rule? How do you go from the alphanumeric string id to the numeric one?

Comment: You are looking something like HASH?

Comment: As @Wonka mentioned, [`hash()`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/hash) is a good option if you have no constraints on the integer ID apart from unique string to int mapping.

Comment: @TheGamer007 Thanks i'll give that a shot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be an option:

```
user_ids = ['8842281e1d1347389f2ab93d60773d4d', '8842281e1d1347389f2ab93d6077rftg']
int_user_ids = [hash(uid) for uid in user_ids]
print(int_user_ids)
```

output

```
[-8469562637978336096, 8436259400936457256]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the original user ids are valid hexadecimal strings, as TheGamer007 pointed out, you can use.

You can use

```py
int(i, 16)
```

```py
user_ids = ['8842281e1d1347389f2ab93d60773d4d', '8842281e1d1347389f2ab93d60773d4d']

id = int(user_ids[0], 16))
```

would return `181118512701639250041046678546423430477`

Comment: This would depend on the user_ids being valid hexadecimal strings, which is not mentioned in the question.